# Unable to find Windows.ApplicationModel

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Hi I am trying to use the Windows.ApplicationModel as in this example 
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Package

However I am unable to import the dll.

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
```

results in an error although I am using .NET Version where it should exist. Also I cannot find it when I try to add the reference. 
Any Ideas?

I need it to get some packe Informations about Programs that run in the ApplicationFrameHost.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you need the Windows SDK 17134 version that comes with the UWP development package in the installer. Then you can use that namespace. Google also led me to this link which might help: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/

Answer (score 0):

For targeting Windows 10 (version 1809?) and greater using .Net 6 and greater the namespaces are automatically available. In a new WPF project created using Visual Studio 2022 if I have *Supported OS Version* set to `10.0.17763.0` or higher then I can use a class in `Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer` and I assume that applies for all of `Windows.ApplicationModel`.